# Non-default panel size not working in Firefox add-ons sdk

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I create a panel in my main.js file with the following code:

```
var pan = panel.Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("start.html"),
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("start.js"), data.url("jquery-1.6.4.min.js")]  
});
```

I'd like to make it larger so I added the width and height properties:

```
var pan = panel.Panel({
  width:400,
  height:400,
  contentURL: data.url("start.html"),
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("start.js"), data.url("jquery-1.6.4.min.js")]  
});
```

After adding these properties the panel gets bigger, however it is also transparent and has no content:

[image]

I'm using sdk version 1.2.1 with Firefox 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Works fine for me using your code and trivial `start.html`/`start.js` files - the panel appears and it is not transparent. It is also unclear why a size change would have any such effect, the `width` and `height` properties merely change the existing private `_width` and `_height` properties. Maybe try to minimize your `start.html` file to figure out which part of it causes the issue.

Comment: Do you have any desktop effects running on your Linux system?

Comment: I tried running it with Ubuntu2D (no effects) and it didn't work either. In that case it didn't come up transparent but just a blank window. I also ran it on Windows where it worked fine so maybe this is a Linux-only issue.

Comment: It's not working on Ubuntu only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed with Firefox 8.